# NVM installation per user is not working with automated ssh logins

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, sshpass, ssh2-exec

Normally when I login to my server via [putty](http://www.putty.org/), I am able to use nvm, grunt, gulp commands but if I connect with php's ssh2 extension or with sshpass through a bash script those commands are not working unless if I execute this commands first:

```
~/.nvm/nvm.sh 
source ~/.profile
nvm current
```

And this is my `~/.profile` file:

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

What seems to be issue ? Why I need to execute this commands every time with automation tools such as [ssh2](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ssh2.php) or [sshpass](https://sourceforge.net/projects/sshpass/) ?

My OS is ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with `sshpass`. You can verify this by running the ssh session without `sshpass`, and you will see that even if you manually enter the password, it will still not work.

When you run ssh with a command after it, it starts a remote shell that is not connected to a TTY, and that shell is not considered a login shell. For non-login shells, .profile simply isn't run.

The simple solution this problem is to move the environment setup from `.profile` to `.bashrc`. `.bashrc` is run even for non-interactive shells, and so should provide the environment setup you need.

As a side note, why are you using sshpass at all? Why not use the more secure public key authentication?

To clarify, the fact that the shell is not connected to a TTY is unrelated to your problem. At least for openssh, you can tell it to open a TTY even if a command to run is provided by specifying `-t` on the command line. `.profile` will still not be run.

Comment: interesting. thank you for the answer. I'll test it.